# How to Set Standard Fields to Read Only for Non-Admin users

Tags: sitecore-client

I have created a new non-admin user role. Now, I want the standard fields on every item to be visible but cannot be editable. For example they cannot edit the value of _Source Item.
[image]
[image]

I have tried disabling the /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/View/Standard Fields in core db, but the new users can still edit the standard fields.

Any advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by restricting the standard fields access in Security editor.
In Security editor, navigate to /sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections where you can see the list of standard fields.

Here I have restricted "Display name" field to read-only. you can try with all the fields which need to be read-only.

[image]